# How do I make an HTML link focus on text

Tags: html, css, header

I can't get the link to only appear on the "TJ" text at the top, it always appears to the right throughout the header. Can someone help? I have been trying to change the header1 to a paragraph, but that hasn't helped. I'm new to HTML and CSS, so if someone could help that would be much appreciated.

```css
/* Imported Fonts*/

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  src: url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.TopRow {
  font-family: Fira Sans, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.Image1Nav {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 2%;
}

.Image1 {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class=T opRow>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
      <h1>
        Tj
      </h1>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<div class='Image1Nav'>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <img class="Image1" src="Images/noimg.jpg" alt="noimg.jpg">
  </a>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident quidem magni impedit totam esse sapiente, molestias exercitationem tenetur nihil libero, consectetur perferendis illum placeat hic. Ipsum rem incidunt omnis sed.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving your `a` tag into the `h1` tag (instead) of the other way around would fix this issue,
as so:

```css
/* Imported Fonts*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans';
    src: url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:red;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

.TopRow{
    
    font-family: Fira Sans, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
.Image1Nav{
    background-color: grey;
    margin:2%;
}
.Image1{
    width:25%;
    padding:2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<head>
        <title>TJ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class = TopRow>
        <h1>
           <a href="https://www.google.com">Tj</a>
        </h1>
        <!-- edits made above -->
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class = 'Image1Nav'>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="Image1" src="Images/noimg.jpg" alt="noimg.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident quidem magni impedit totam esse sapiente, molestias exercitationem tenetur nihil libero, consectetur perferendis illum placeat hic. Ipsum rem incidunt omnis sed.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a link inside an h1 tag try putting the anchor within your h1 tag.

```
<h1>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Tj</a>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `a` tag inside of the `h1` tag fixes your issue like so:

```
<h1>
   <a href="https://www.google.com">
   Tj
   </a>
</h1>
```

```css
/* Imported Fonts*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans';
    src: url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('Fonts/firasans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:red;
}
a:visited{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

.TopRow{
    
    font-family: Fira Sans, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
.Image1Nav{
    background-color: grey;
    margin:2%;
}
.Image1{
    width:25%;
    padding:2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<head>
        <title>TJ</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class = TopRow>
        
        <h1>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
        Tj
        </a>
        </h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class = 'Image1Nav'>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="Image1" src="Images/noimg.jpg" alt="noimg.jpg">
        </a>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident quidem magni impedit totam esse sapiente, molestias exercitationem tenetur nihil libero, consectetur perferendis illum placeat hic. Ipsum rem incidunt omnis sed.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```